# Remove whatever text is before the last comma

Tags: r

Having a dataframe like this:

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), text = c("text, another, end","not, keep","not, to keep, this","finally, chance, to, check"))
```

How is is possible to detect which is the last comma in the text column of every row and remove whatever is before this.

Example of expected output:

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), text = c("end","keep","this","check"))
```

Comment: Try: `sub(".*, *", "", x$text)`

Comment: `sub('.*, ', '', df$text)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sub`, we can remove all content up to, and including, the final comma, plus any whitespace which might follow that final comma.

```
df$text <- sub("^.*,\\s*", "", df$text)
df

id  text
1  1   end
2  2  keep
3  3  this
4  4 check
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4),
                 text = c("text, another, end","not, keep",
                          "not, to keep, this","finally, chance, to, check"))
```

Answer (score 2):

regex are default greedy in nature so you don't really need to find the last comma per se

```
sub('.*, ', '', df$text)
#[1] "end"   "keep"  "this"  "check"
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R, more verbose, less efficient, no regex:

```
df <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$text), ", "), function(x){x[length(x)]})
```